# How to configure Visual Studio Code Docker extension to use a remote host while keeping DOCKER_HOST variable empty in local terminals?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code for Windows, how can I set the Docker host for the [Docker extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-docker) (to be some remote machine), but still have it so that when I open a terminal, the DOCKER_HOST variable will **not** be set (will be empty so that I can refer to the local Docker).

The [vscode documentation says](https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/develop-remote-host#_a-basic-remote-example), to set the remote docker host, you should set DOCKER_HOST.  That's what I did and that's how I get the extension to show me docker containers that are on the remote machine -- that much is desirable.  But when I open a terminal, it unfortunately also sets the DOCKER_HOST variable (in this terminal's environment) to point to the remote machine, preventing me from executing docker commands on my local docker host in that terminal.

I find I too often forget to unset the variable before executing a docker command in a terminal and I find it annoying that it's being set automatically.

What I want is to be able to set which host the Docker extension is using (so I can see a list of containers from the remote host in the extension's container explorer view, for example)  But when I launch a terminal, I want the DOCKER_HOST environment variable **not** to be set, so that I can interact with my local docker for Windows.

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I'm having the same...

Comment: @ricber, no solution yet, no.